# Lambda function returning lvalue from higher scope

Tags: c++, lambda, reference, lvalue

```
int main() {
    int x;
    auto& getx = [&]() {
        return x;
    }
    
    getx() = 1;
}
```

This doesn't seem possible, as it gives me:

*error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'main()::<lambda()>&' to an rvalue of type 'main()::<lambda()>'|*

**Why ? and how to do it**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda expression creates a temporary object (called a closure) of an unknown class type.  Temporary objects can't be assigned to non-const references.  That means you need

```
auto&& getx = [&]() {
    return x;
}
```

so that you get an rvalue reference to the closure, or

```
auto getx = [&]() {
    return x;
}
```

so you just get the closure.

That will get the code to compile, but still needs one more bit to make `getx`'s return value to be a reference to `x`.  To do that you need to add

```
auto getx = [&]() -> int& {
    return x;
}

// or

auto getx = [&]() -> auto& {
    return x;
}

// or

auto getx = [&]() -> decltype(auto) {
    return x;
};
```

---

Also note that `main` must **always** return an `int`.  You should turn up your compiler warning level so that it errors out if you try and use `void main`.

Comment: thx for the quick reply, however, what I asked for was a lvalue, and these two aren't

Comment: @Sho What go you want `getx` to be?  Do you want it to be a reference to `x`, or do you want it to return a reference to `x`, or do you want to to return the value of `x`?

Comment: quoting the title "Lambda function returning lvalue from higher scope" basicly something that alows me this `getx() = 1;`

Comment: @Sho Okay, I've updated the answer to include that part as well.

Comment: nice answer as well, and in the end better constructed than the other one! The other helped me quicklier though, but yours explained it well

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify that lambda returns reference to int - `int&`, and call closure by `()`:

```
auto& getx = [&]() -> int& { // -> int& added
    return x;
}();                         // () added
```

Temporary value cannot be bound to *lvalue* reference. If you want to make `getx` to be as a reference to `x` variable, you have to return reference from your lambda.

Comment: You can also use `-> auto&` to not specify the type

Comment: Really big thank you for that, it comes along very nicely with the rest of my code, and made me learn about closure 